# Which lattices can be represented as the lattice of closed sets in a topological space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

I sometimes come across families of sets that are closed under *arbitrary intersection*, but have finite joins that are not unions, e.g.

1. ideals
2. deductively closed sets in some deductive system
3. filters

We can think of these things as lattices $\Lambda$ in the language $(\land, \lor)$, with an additional second-order constraint promising us that infinite meets make sense.

**I'm curious under what circumstances we can *represent* one of these lattices as the lattice of closed sets on a topological space $(X, \tau)$.**

I've tried a lot of things to try to build myself a point-set representation of an arbitrary (distributive) lattice (with a global maximum and minimum). Intuitively, filters and especially ultrafilters act a lot like element-elements in a family of sets. So, I tried making my point set $X$ the ultrafilters in $\Lambda$ (and declare the representation of a lattice element $a$ to be the set of ultrafilters containing it), since that respects $\land$ and $\lor$ but I immediately ran into problems.

If we take the lattice of closed sets of the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), $\{ \{a, b\}, \{b\}, \varnothing \}$, there's only one ultrafilter, so it collapses down to the two-element Boolean algebra.

I also tried taking my lattice $\Lambda$ and adding a new formal operation the *formal relative complement*, $a \setminus b$, to try to build myself a larger Boolean lattice for $\Lambda$ to embed into, and then take ultrafilters there. My intuition is breaking down though and I remember from looking at Boolean algebras previously that they can have few or no atoms or otherwise be really badly behaved.

So, at this point, I'm taking a step and wondering which lattices can be represented as the lattices of closed sets in topological spaces in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By dualizing, you are asking for the sup-lattices that are isomorphic to the sup-lattice of open sets of a topological space. These sup-lattices are actually [frames](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/frame) (see also [frame of opens](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/frame+of+opens)), meaning that apart from the suprema $\vee$ we also have *finite* infima $\wedge$ such that the distributive law
$$V \wedge \bigvee_{i \in I} U_i = \bigvee_{i \in I} (V \wedge U_i)$$
holds. There is a well-known contravariant [adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor) between frames and topological spaces (which is usally presented in a different form using [locales](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locale), covariantly, but let's keep the language of frames for the moment, since you have asked for lattices), which I describe below.

#### From spaces to frames

If $X$ is a topological space, its topology $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is a frame. Every continuous map $f : X \to Y$ induces a morphism of frames $f^* : \mathcal{O}(Y) \to \mathcal{O}(X)$.

#### From frames to spaces

If $F$ is a frame, then we define a topological space $P(F)$ as follows. The points of $P(F)$ are the complete prime filters on $F$. These are subsets $\mathcal{P} \subseteq F$ with

- $\top \in \mathcal{P}$ (where $\top$ denotes the largest element of $F$)
- If $U \leq V$ and $U \in \mathcal{P}$, then $V \in \mathcal{P}$
- If $U,V \in \mathcal{P}$, then $U \wedge V \in \mathcal{P}$
- If $\bigvee_{i \in I} U_i \in \mathcal{P}$, then $U_i \in \mathcal{P}$ for some $i$.

The sets $\{\mathcal{P} : U \in \mathcal{P} \}$ for $U \in F$ constitute a topology on the set of complete prime filters. For example, $\bigcup_{i \in I} \{\mathcal{P} : U_i \in \mathcal{P} \} = \{\mathcal{P} : \bigvee_{i \in I} U_i \in \mathcal{P}\}$, and the other topology axioms follow similarly.

If $\varphi : F \to G$ is a morphism of frames, we get a continuous map $\varphi^* : P(G) \to P(F)$ mapping a prime filter $\mathcal{Q} \subseteq G$ to the prime filter $\{U \in F : \varphi(U) \in \mathcal{Q}\} \subseteq F$.

#### Adjunction

If $X$ is a topological space, there is a continuous map $X \to P(\mathcal{O}(X))$ mapping $x \in X$ to the prime filter $[x] := \{U \in \mathcal{O}(X) : x \in U\}$ of open sets (also called a principal filter).

If $F$ is a frame, there is a morphism of frames $F \to \mathcal{O}(P(F))$ mapping $U \in F$ to the open set $\{\mathcal{P} : U \in \mathcal{P} \}$.

The triangle identities hold. So we see that $\mathcal{O} : \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Frm}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is left adjoint to $P : \mathbf{Frm}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Top}$.

#### Answer

Every adjunction restricts to an equivalence of categories between its fixed points. This is formal, but luckily, we can in fact the determine these fixed points for this adjunction (for a proof, see the references below).

- For a topological space $X$, the map $X \to P(\mathcal{O}(X))$ is an isomorphism iff $X$ is [sober](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space).
- For a frame $F$, the map $F \to \mathcal{O}(P(F))$ is an isomorphism iff $F$ is **spatial**.

The condition of being spatial is usually described in terms of the locale (the dual object), but here it explicitly means:

- For all $U,V \in F$ with $U \neq V$ there must be some complete prime filter $\mathcal{P}$ on $F$ such that either $U \in \mathcal{P}, V \notin \mathcal{P}$ or $U \notin \mathcal{P}, V \in \mathcal{P}$.

This essentially says that $F$ has "enough" complete prime filters.

Notice that this condition is evident when $F = \mathcal{O}(X)$: If $U,V$ are two distinct open subsets, then there is some $x \in X$ with $x \in U$, $x \notin V$ or $x \in V$, $x \notin U$, so the (principal) prime filter $[x]$ distinguishes $U$ and $V$.

#### The role of the Sierpinski space

The Sierpinski space $\mathbb{S}$ has two structures. On the one hand, it is a topological space. Observe that the underlying set of $\mathcal{O}(X)$ identifies with the set of continuous maps $X \to \mathbb{S}$. That this set carries the structure of a frame (which is natural in $X$) exactly means that $\mathbb{S}$ is a frame object internal to $\mathbf{Top}$. Concretely, this means that its underlying set has a frame structure, and the frame operations $\vee,\wedge$ are continuous operations. This is the second structure. It allows us to construct, for every frame $F$, the topological space of frame morphisms $F \to \mathbb{S}$, which - you guessed it - exactly identifies with the space $P(F)$ we defined above.

So in some sense, the Sierpinski space/frame leverages the whole adjunction here. It is a prominent example of a [dualizing object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizing+object).

#### An example from commutative algebra

The ideals of a commutative ring $R$ form a complete lattice, but not a frame. In contrast, the [radical ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal) form a frame with the operations
$$\bigvee_{i \in I} I_i = \sqrt{\sum_{i \in I} I_i}, \quad I \wedge J = I \cap J,$$
in particular $\bot = \sqrt{0}$ and $\top = R$. It turns out that the radical ideals can be identified with the open subsets of a topological space: namely the [prime spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring) $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. Indeed, the complete prime filters are $\{I : I \not\subseteq \mathfrak{p}\}$ for prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq R$, and the fact that radical ideals are intersections of prime ideals implies that the frame is spatial.

#### References

If you want to know more, have a look at chapter IX in the book

> Saunders Mac Lane, Ieke Moerdijk, *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic. A first introduction to topos theory*, Springer (1992)

Comment: Oups. I fixed this. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*, Johnstone's book *Stone Spaces* is a great reference.